# /~ URL pages will not load, but full path /.../..../ will load - security issu

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration, mac-osx, httpd.conf

I am pretty new to Apache - New sys admin that inherited a broken server and I've been slowly making it work.

We have the default directory that is hosting staff webpages and is working normally.

The hiccup is that there is a different directory that is supposed to host multiple websites as projects and demonstrations and I was getting a permission error when accessing those sites.
I preformed the following permission changes:
chmod +rx /path to directory
chown _www:_www /patch to directory

Now the full path works but I'm being told that is somewhat insecure as previously the /~directory/... would pull up the pages webpage, that is no longer the case, I get "Forbidden you don't have permission.

I've been trying to adjust the httpd.conf file and the httpd-userdir.conf but it does not seem to work.

I know it is most likely a file permission error, but I for the life of me am not sure where.

I would appreciate any thoughts or answers you might have...and please be gentle with me lol.

Comment: Please share the configuration you use, the exact request you have tried and error log when the event happens.